# How to find records having specific repetitions mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large table with 800k records. The structure of the table is as follows:

```
Table: chapters
Columns: Id chapter author  pages   book_id
```

Some of the records have repetitions according to the following pattern:

```
id  chapter author  pages   book_id
64478   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller            1665112051456
64479   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen         1665112051456
64480   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües            1665112051456
64481   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling            1665112051456
64482   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling Helen A. Fielding          1665112051456
64483   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling Helen A. Fielding Gabrielle Hiltmann           1665112051456
64484   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling Helen A. Fielding Gabrielle Hiltmann Silvia Stoller            1665112051456
64485   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling Helen A. Fielding Gabrielle Hiltmann Silvia Stoller Kelly Oliver           1665112051456
64486   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling Helen A. Fielding Gabrielle Hiltmann Silvia Stoller Kelly Oliver Sara Heinämaa         1665112051456
64487   Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller Debra B. Bergoffen Christina Schües Veronica Vasterling Helen A. Fielding Gabrielle Hiltmann Silvia Stoller Kelly Oliver Sara Heinämaa Annemie Halsema         1665112051456
```

is there any way to find and delete the whole book_id of such records?

if alone mysql is not enough for it then anything in a php script is also welcomed.

thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the whole book_id without keeping one?

Comment: Yes I want to delete the whole book_id.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting the whole duplicate book_id s you can use this query:

```
delete from chapters where book_id in 
  (select book_id from chapters group by book_id having count(*) > 1);
```

If you want to keep the last book_id and delete the rest you can use this code:

```
delete from chapters where 
   id not in (select max(id) from chapters group by book_id );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wont work in my case as I want to search  from the chapter column and if the records have repetitions then delete the whole book_id. The query you have provided will delete every duplicate book_id regardless of repetitions in the chapter column.

Comment: no problem, please provide more explanation about your desired repetition rule.

Comment: As you can see in the above question, in the record number 64478, chapter is "Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller." In the records number 64479, "Veronica Vasterling & Silvia Stoller" is repeated and also "Debra B. Bergoffen" is added. So every new record is adding the previous record in it. This is the repeating I need to delete.